# How to read and modify the data in oracle database (instead of using Replace function)

Tags: sql, oracle, function, replace

I have just started to learn and work with Oracle SQL a few months ago, and I have a question that I could not find similar problems on Stack Overflow.

In SQL Oracle,
I am trying to find a way that I can read the data from a column and modify (add/subtract) the data.  What I have got so far is using **replace** like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496761/replace-multiple-characters-in-sql), but I do not want to use multiple **replace** function to make it work. I am not sure whether you guys understand my question, so I have listed what I have so far below, and I used multiple **replace** function.

```
      COMMOD_CODE (Given)  |      MODEL(Desired_result)
                           |
       X2-10GB-LR          |        X2-10GB-LR (same)
       15454-OSC-CSM       |        15454-OSC
       15454-PP64LC        |        15454-PP_64-LC
       CAT3550             |        WS-C3550-48-SMI
       CAT3560G-48         |        WS-C3560G-48PS-S
       CAT3550             |        WS-C3550-48-SMI   
       DWDM-GBIC-30        |        DWDM-GBIC-30.33   



Select 
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(commod.COMMODITY_CODE, 
  '15454-OSC-CSM', '15454-OSC'),
  '15454-PP64LC','15454-PP_64-LC'),
  'CAT3550','WS-C3550-48-SMI'),
  'CAT3560G-48','WS-C3560G-48PS-S'),
  'CAT3550','WS-C3550-48-SMI'),
  'DWDM-GBIC-30','DWDM-GBIC-30.33')
   MODEL,
   NVL(commod.COMMODITY_CODE, ' ') as COMMOD_CODE
FROM tablename.table commod
```

I got the the answer. However, I think I used a lot of ** REPLACE ** to get it right. So, my question is if there is any easier way to do that instead of using **replace** multiple times, and make your script look awful.

Is someone able to please give me some guidance?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Use `DECODE` or `CASE` for this, I think.  Or, better yet, maybe a mapping table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *DECODE* function in this case:

```
with
  test_data as (
    select '15454-OSC-CSM' as COMMODITY_CODE from dual
    union all select '15454-PP64LC' from dual
    union all select 'CAT3550' from dual
    union all select 'CAT3560G-48' from dual
    union all select 'CAT3550' from dual
    union all select 'DWDM-GBIC-30' from dual
  )
select
  decode(COMMODITY_CODE,
    '15454-OSC-CSM', '15454-OSC',
    '15454-PP64LC', '15454-PP_64-LC',
    'CAT3550', 'WS-C3550-48-SMI',
    'CAT3560G-48', 'WS-C3560G-48PS-S',
    'CAT3550', 'WS-C3550-48-SMI',
    'DWDM-GBIC-30', 'DWDM-GBIC-30.33')
  from test_Data
;
```

Result:

```
COL
------------------
15454-OSC         
15454-PP_64-LC    
WS-C3550-48-SMI   
WS-C3560G-48PS-S  
WS-C3550-48-SMI   
DWDM-GBIC-30.33
```

What the *DECODE* function does: it checks its first argument - if it is equal to the second argument, then it returns the third argument, otherwise, if it is equal to the 4th argument, it returns the 5th argument, and so on.