# How to replace multiple strings in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I looked up a discussion in SO with the link below :
[Replace multiple characters in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496761/replace-multiple-characters-in-sql)

What I am not able to understand is why the query is not working for :

```
select table_value, 
   replace(replace(replace(table_value, 'M', 'MEETING'), 'E', 'EMAIL'), 'P', 'PHONE') required_value 
from foobar
```

I am a beginner learner in SQL and want to understand what's wrong with the above query ?
I'd appreciate if someone could help me picturise the backend working here.

The accepted answer in that blog is not the ultimate solution. I wanna know what to do when I come across a situation where there are multiple strings in a column which needs to be replaced?

Is there an easy and efficient alternative or not?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Edit your question and show the values in `table_value` and what you want them to be.

Comment: See the blog...My reference is from that discussion

Comment: By blog you mean linked question?

Comment: Yeah,  from that linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted will work, it just won't give correct results.

take this example data:

```
create table #foobar (table_value varchar (100))

Insert into #foobar
values ('M,E'), ('M,E,P'), ('E'), ('M,P')
Insert into #foobar
values ('P,E')
```

When you run:

```
select table_value, 
   replace(replace(replace(table_value, 'M', 'MEETING'), 'E', 'EMAIL'), 'P', 'PHONE') required_value 
from #foobar
```

You get these results

```
table_value required_value
M,E          MEMAILEMAILTING,EMAIL
M,E,P        MEMAILEMAILTING,EMAIL,PHONE
E            EMAIL
M,P          MEMAILEMAILTING,PHONE
P,E          PHONE,EMAIL
```

As you can see the problem is that in replacing m with meeting, you now have two new 'E' values in the text that will in turn get replaced with email.

So if you want to fix this the first and best solution is to stop storing data this way. Comma delimited lists in a field are almost always a bad idea. It violates the first normal form. You should have a related table where each type in the list is a separate record attached to the same id value from the original table. This is database 101.

However at times, you may be stuck with this, that's why the link wants to split the data out into a table and then process from there, then join it back into one field after updating if you need to retain the current structure and aren't just processing data in a staging table. Or alternatively not use values that will mingle as these do.

Comment: Yeah but assuming I'm stuck with a scenario as above ...So is there any other simple alternative ? Or I have to go with nesting of REPLACE  ?

Comment: There are no simple fixes because your data model is poorly designed. The link has the actual fixes, use those.

Comment: Thank you so much. I couldn't have figured it without your clear explanation.Keep up the good work :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is if you replace

```
M -> MEETING
```

and then

```
E -> EMAIL
```

you end with:

```
MEMAILEMAILTING
```

Maybe you can do a workaround if you use the comma as separator

```
select table_value, 
   replace(replace(replace(table_value, 'M,', 'MEETING,'), 'E,', 'EMAIL,'), 'P,', 'PHONE,') required_value 
from foobar
```

But then your starting data should include one ending coma:

```
table_value
M,E,
M,E,P,
E,  
M,P,
P,E,
```

Comment: Yeah but isn't E supposed to be replaced with EMAIL and not MEETING? Or is the first occurence of E making it to be replaced with EMAIL?

Comment: You are chaining replace, so the replace occurs to the previous result not the original string, So after you replace `M -> MEETING` you have `EE` more than before

Comment: I guess I'll have to chain cleverly in such cases. Although I believe such scenarios may occur rarely unless you have a poorly designed database.

Comment: As I show you, if you `replace(table_value, 'M,', 'MEETING,')` You can avoid the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
select case [replace] when 'M' then 'MEETING' 
             when 'E' then 'EMAIL'  
             when 'P' then 'PHONE'  end 'required_value' 
  from your_table
```